# Fundamental solution of a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the fundamental solution of  $x''+\dfrac{x'}{t}-\dfrac{4x}{t^2}=0$.

I have converted to its equivalent linear homogeneous system including variable $y(t)$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'(t)\\ 
y'(t)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
\dfrac{4}{t^2} & -\frac{1}{t}\ 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x(t)\\ 
y(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that finding the fundamental solution is finding the linear combination of the eigenvectors, then multiply them by its eigenvalues. But I'm kinda of stuck as to how to find the fundamental solution.

Comment: Be careful using an eigen-decomposition of the coefficient matrix when it is not constant!  Dicey at best!  Cheers!

Comment: Please enlighten me!

Comment: If $A(t)$ is your matrix, the solution won't be $e^{\int A(t)dt}$ unless $A(t)$ and $\int A(t)$ commute, $[A(t), \int A(t) dt] = 0$.  Try calculating $de^{\int A(t)dt}/dt$ from the power series and see what happens!  Cheerio!

Comment: this is cauchy equation. turn into a linear, constant coefficient equation by a change of variable $\ln t = \tau, t = e^\tau$

Comment: @RobertLewis, I tried solving it normal and the matrices just started getting messy. I tried what you said and i got $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & e^t \\ 
\frac{4e^\frac{-4}{t^2}}{t^2} & -\frac{1}{t^2}
\end{bmatrix}$ I am trying to see the beauty or and HA-HA moment in this but can't find any

Comment: I was trying to give an example of why $e^{\int A(t)dt}$ *won't* work unless $[A(t), \int A(t) dt] = 0$ for *all* $t$!

Comment: @RobertLewis, sorry if i came across rude but do I continuing solving  the messy matrix  or am I missing a point a here

Comment: You didn't seem rude;  I'm rushing off to work now and can't say more 'til  later!  You can find the fundamental from Jack's solution;  send me a reminder later on tonite if you still need input and I'll say more.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deal with non-constant coefficients as they were constant.

However, by setting $x(t)=f(4\sqrt{t})$ the original ODE is mapped to:
$$ 4\,f(4\sqrt{t})+\sqrt{t}\, f'(4\sqrt{t})+4t\,f''(4\sqrt{t})=0 \tag{1}$$
or to:
$$ 16\, f(z) + z\,f'(z) + z^2\,f''(z)=0 \tag{2}$$
that can be solved by standard methods. For instance, by setting $z=e^t$ we have that the solutions of $(2)$ are given by:
$$ f(z) = C_1 \cos(4\log z)+C_2 \sin(4\log z) $$
so the solutions of the original ODE are given by:
$$ x(t) = K_1 t^2 + K_2 t^{-2}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Wouldn't that be the general solution to the homogeneous equation which I already got.  But I am trying to find the fundamental matrix for homogeneous linear system

Comment: I am studying for an exam that is why and  its asks Find the general solution to the homogeneous function and the fundamental matrix for homogeneous linear system

Comment: @user124473: how can that method apply here, with non-constant coefficients?